# How to safely earn interest on business profits (UK)

Tags: small-business, interest

I have a good sized amount of money in a UK (Barclays) business bank account earning exactly zero interest. I'd be happy even to earn 1% interest on that money so long as it was totally safe, but I don't know what my options are (if any). I would like it to be a mechanism whereby I can release the money back to my company at short notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deposit it in a business savings account. The following below show you some options you can choose from.

- [Moneysupermarket](http://www.moneysupermarket.com/business-finance/business-savings-accounts/)
- [MoneyFacts](http://moneyfacts.co.uk/business/business-savings-accounts)
- [Money](http://www.money.co.uk/savings-accounts/business-savings-accounts.htm)

Next you can invest it in the market i.e. shares, bonds etc. If you have a more risky side, can go for peer to peer lending.

If you are feeling really lucky and want to invest in the long term, then buy a property as a buy-to-let landlord. There are loads of options, you only need to explore.

Comment: I never even knew there was such a thing as a business savings account, so thanks for that. Not so sure the other suggestions could be considered totally safe.

Answer (score 0):

I found some UK personal accounts offer up to 3% interest (no names here, but it is well known bank with red logo). You can take out directors loan from your company, put the cash into that personal account and earn interest. Just don't forget to return this loan before end of financial year, so this interest does not become your dividends.

Comment: The high interest personal accounts I've seen all seem to only offer the interest on the first two or three thousand pounds... anything above that gets zero interest :-(

Comment: Mine works up to 20K, but it is not a savings account and you need to have 2 direct debits and pay in £500 every month.